# Grub doesn't show up after installation of Fedora 23

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, fedora, grub

Initially, I wanted to install Fedora in UEFI, but I don't know for which reason, I had the message 
"For a UEFI installation, you must include an EFI System partition on a GPT formatted disk, monted at /boot/efi". 
The weird part is also when I boot in UEFI mode, it doesn't detect my hard drive.

So I decided to install fedora in legacy mode, it worked fine but the Grub doesn'tshow up.

My fdisk :

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 409599999 408573952 194.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       409600000 410623999   1024000   500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       410624000 976773119 566149120   270G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       410626048 741892095 331266048   158G 8e Linux LVM
```

When I do a `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
it does find all my partitions

```
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
```

I did a grub2-install /dev/sda, that didn't worked either.

Result of `bootinfoscript`

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
    location.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.04 2011-04-18
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 4638440 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the syslinux 
                       directory. No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /syslinux/syslinux.cfg /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /syslinux/ldlinux.sys

korora-root': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

korora-home': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

korora-swap': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2           1,026,048   409,599,999   408,573,952   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         409,600,000   410,623,999     1,024,000  83 Linux
/dev/sda4         410,624,000   976,773,119   566,149,120   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         410,626,048   741,892,095   331,266,048  8e Linux LVM


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8004829184 bytes, 15634432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *              2    15,634,431    15,634,430   b W95 FAT32


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/mapper/korora-home 348b456b-1e3f-4022-8cd6-1fcab21f504a   ext4       
/dev/mapper/korora-root 89fa9032-4463-467b-bada-43d3e166358e   ext4       
/dev/mapper/korora-swap c9df224c-ccf9-4cc2-ad15-bc9b0eb4e7d6   swap       
/dev/sda1        A806534E06531D1E                       ntfs       Réservé au système
/dev/sda2        CE50C5D650C5C605                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        c6e42dd8-266b-4cf3-9d6a-c77bf0cc7e77   ext4       
/dev/sda5        BHRFKE-yv7M-6lUj-Ouez-Qn0Y-KPis-gwiKoG LVM2_member 
/dev/sdb1        7217-0681                              vfat       LIVE

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
korora-home
korora-root
korora-swap

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/korora-home /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/korora-root /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/sda3        /boot                    ext4       (rw,relatime,seclabel,stripe=4,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1        /run/media/danilo_d/LIVE vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Have an idea ?

Comment: By "the Grub doesn't show up" do you mean that the system boots into Fedora but skips the Grub screen, or it doesn't boot to Grub / Fedora at all?

Comment: IIUC your machine is using UEFI boot. You could boot into Fedora if you switched to legacy in "BIOS" (yes, it is not BIOS, it is EFI or what...) but then you could not boot into UEFI Windows. One usually can not mix UEFI and "legacy" boot. Perhaps the easiest would be to reinstall Fedora, and during partitioning make sure /dev/sdb1 is used as /boot/efi mount point.